# Count of instances in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I am using Geometry Nodes in Blender, based on an input image, and scaled instances based on the image color. Is there a way to know how many instances are display (scale > 0) ?

[image]

Comment: There is *Point Separate* which you could use based on this condition, and see the resulting spreadsheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check BEFORE you instantiate if the value of your scaling is greater than *0*, and use that selection when instantiating.

After that you can query the number of instantiated objects with the node `Domain Size`.

[image]